# Link Text wrong color(s) in Firefox

Tags: css, windows, firefox, cleartype

Ok, weirdest thing....

Working at home and opened html document in Firefox 3.6 and my link text is wrong colors and looks multi-colored.

Any ideas?

Looks fine in IE, Chrome, Opera and Firefox 3.6 on my work machine.
I mean the difference is shockingly bad.[image]

In this graphic the numbers in parenthesis should be simple light gray (#999) and the link text should be blue (#034ea2).  But as you can see its all gone odd, green and yellow and forget the hover states... I am using percentage sizes on the text via CSS - but that shouldn't do this, should it?

This machine does differ from my normal work machine, but I don't think it's a windows setting as the colors look fine in other browsers.

This seems like an old IE problem - so it's freakin me out that good ole FF is doing it to me.

Any ideas?

Windows Cleartype was the problem. Must have been reset on my home machine by any number of Windows updates I've had in the last week.  Thanks Joshusman! Sometimes the simplest things are the hardest fixes to find.

Comment: can you post some code for us to look at, otherwise its hard to help. Perhaps put the code in a http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Comment: Can we see the CSS/HTML/code?  That'd be great, thanks.

Comment: It's not different because it's a visited link is it?

Comment: You should give johusman the correct answer to this one! Incredible answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off ClearType in Windows, in case this is some weird subpixel rendering problem.

Comment: I'm aware, and it's a long shot, but he also says it works at work in the same browser. Can't hurt.
Though one of the reasons it came to my mind was the way the screenshot looks, but now I realize much of it is probably the crappy jpeg quality...

Comment: no the jpeg is actually pretty close to what it actually looks like

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you!  Clear type was the problem (for the life of me I couldn't remember what that was called but remembered there was something when IE7 came out)... any way - how weird was that?  @#$%# Windows... funny only effected FF - but that fixed it... css hex colors are displaying properly now and my vision is saved!

Comment: I'm sort of taken aback myself :)

Comment: FF doesn't do a very good job at text rendering. It gets worse in FF 4.

Comment: that is not a comforting proposition... now add the fact that I need full UTF-8 support (i mean full - Thai, Hindi, Russian..) and my options only get more and more limited.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is [CSS Pseudo Classes](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp)